# Write into properties file with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have found this link http://javahonk.com/angularjs-read-property-file-value/ on how to read from a property file, but I don't know how I could change the values in it. 
For example, let's say I have in that file an object like: {id: 1, name: "John"}; I get this and bind the name to a textbox, but then I want to change the value and save it. How can this be done?

Comment: You cannot write into files on the client's device with javascript without user interaction (ie. prompting the user for a file selection).

Comment: I don't want to write on the client's device. I want to write on the server where all my app files are. in a folder just like in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is possible to access File System only in latest Chrome. It is however not standardized and user has to approve the webpage to access to his file system

> To use PERSISTENT storage, you must obtain permission from the user to store peristent data

See documentation here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

> In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec is not being considered by other browsers. For now, the API is Chrome-specific and it's unlikely to be implemented by other browsers and is no longer being standardized with the W3C.